# Get Shellcode from Object Dump the right way

Tags: c, objdump

I have read several tutorials on basic shellcoding and i have a question. I have written a little function in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h> 
int main() {
    char cmd[] = "net user /add jango Jango01$";
    system(cmd);
}
```

and have build an object file of it using

```
gcc -c exec.c -o exec.o
```

Now i want to turn it into shellcode by using objdump.

```
c:\>objdump -d -M intel exec.o

:     file format pe-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_main>:
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
   6:   83 ec 30                sub    esp,0x30
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   e <_main+0xe>
============= SNIP =============
  5c:   c9                      leave  
  5d:   c3                      ret    
  5e:   90                      nop
  5f:   90                      nop
```

When i bundle the bytes to something like

```
char code[] = "\x55\x89\xe5\x83\xe4\xf0\x83\xec\x30\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00 == SNIPPET == \xc9\xc3\x90\x90";
```

is this the correct way? I am not sure if the hexdump is the final shellcode. My english is not so good and i am not sure if i understood all right.

Thank you

Comment: Is this the correct way for what? If you are asking whether the syntax produces an array of `char` containing the values indicated, then yes. But you could just as well ask if `uint8_t code[] = { 0x55, 0x89, …, 0x90 };` does that, and the answer would still be yes. If you are asking whether it works as a "shellcode" for some specific purpose, who knows.

Comment: ..the correct way of getting the binary shellcode, as I have asked. Because i am not sure if objdump or hexdump gives me all needed code.

Comment: `objdump` does show you the dump of the code with the values as hexadecimal. If you want an array of bytes/`char` with those values, then yes you can type in those values into a string with `\x??` escapes, or you can type them into an array as `0x??` – same result. But this is like asking if `char nop = '\x90';`or `char nop = 0x90;` (same result) is the correct way to get a char with an x86 NOP opcode in it.

Comment: So all the surrounding stuff shown in hexdump is not essentially to run the system("net user...") command, right? I only need objdump code?

Comment: So, the question has nothing at all to do with how you "bundle the bytes" to `char code[]`, but about whether there is sufficient information in the output (that we don't see) so that it can be executed in some unknown situation (that we don't know) when (presumably) injected as shellcode to some program (that we don't know) in some format (that we can't even guess at)? =)

Comment: My question wasnt about how to bundle the bytes. It was like about "am i bundeling the right bytes?" because - again - hexdump gives a lot more output..

Comment: Yes, and that question cannot be answered based on the vague information available. Try and see?

Comment: Ok, i will try it once more. I get a big output with hexdump - i get a smaller output with objdump - i took the output of objdump. You dont see errors?

Comment: Well, to be honest it is unlikely to work (at least how you expect) since it probably assumes addresses for things defined in that file (but almost certainly irrelevant to what you actually want to do), like `_main`.

Comment: That's only like 40 lines of assembly output from `objdump -S exec.o`. Why don't you post it alll?

Comment: Basically, you can find many full tutorials over the net. See for example [here](http://tuttlem.github.io/2017/10/28/executing-shellcode-in-c.html).

Comment: This assembly code has references to shared libraries, it's hardly going to work.The shellcode should be wrote in assembly using syscalls...

Comment: Thank you, i would give you a point for that but i cant.

Comment: I just snip it because i thought it was irrelevant.

Comment: @Stacky I would advice you give us: the full output, the full code; the OS you are on; and the way you get the shellcode; and provide any references; if you have any; like tried things but didn't work; and be a bit more specific in the problem-what is exactly the problem? How are we going to try to help; if we don't have the full output? :)